# Utilizando o stateparams não está retornando o json para exibir no detalhe

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Galera, estou com o seguinte problema:

tenho um arquivo json, e estou fazendo a chamada dele assim:

```
$http.get("../templates/teste.json").success(function (response) {

    $scope.x = response;

});
```

Na minha rota, está assim:

```
.state('app.detalhe', {
    url: '/produtos/:ProdutoId',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/detalhe.html',
            controller: 'ProdutosCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

No meu controller, está assim:

```
$scope.produtoSingle = function () {

     x[$stateParams.produtoId]; }

}
```

A url está mandando correto:

E ele simplesmente nao me retorna nada do detalhe, alguem saberia me dizer oque está acontecendo?

Comment: Corrigindo: 
    x[$stateParams.produtoId];

}

Comment: produtoId no lugar de frutaId? Você pode editar seu post, vou corrigir pra ti. Como está o seu arquivo JSON?

Comment: isso, produtoId no lugar de frutaId. Meu json está assim:

Comment: [
  {
    "title":"Título",
    "subtitle":"Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    "title":"Título 2",
    "subtitle":"Lorem ipsum 2",
  },
  {
    "title":"Título 3",
    "subtitle":"Lorem ipsum 3",
  }
]

Comment: você definiu o `$stateParams` no `controller`? o seu `$stateParams.produtoId` está com syntax diferente do parametro no router, que é `ProdutoId`. Qualquer coisa se não resolver, atualize com seu controller completo (ou pelo menos a inicialização) para verificar.

Comment: essa chave depois do array `x[ ... ];` está sobrando... além disso o "x" é `this.x`

Answer (score 0):

Veja minha resposta em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100066/8386

Tente:

```
$http.get("../templates/teste.json").success(function (response) {

    $scope.x = response;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
});
```